# Jmeter Compatibility with liferay DXP

Tags: jmeter, liferay-7

I am trying to run a Jmeter Login script, I am doing every thing correct 
1.HTTP cookie Manager is added.
2.CSRF token p_auth is handled.

After execution in View Result Tree (Browser Mode) showing Portlet is Unavailable.
[image]

Comment: Jmeter is compatible with liferay afik. But the best way to debug is to record it first and have the original xml and after adding a debug sampler check if the csrf token you handled is correct not. Otherwise, you can look for blazemeter for recording. 
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-

Comment: csrf token is correctly handled.I have gone through log..there is no issue with csrf token.

Comment: ok. I don't see any issue in jmeter other than the csrf token. But, there is one jmeter slack group you can join if you like and clarify. https://jmeterusers.slack.com/

Comment: Well, Liferay speaks http, jmeter as well. That means they're compatible. But: If you do everything correctly (as you state)... what's your question?

Comment: what you see on Browser view is irrelevant to your problem, it's just a preview of the page. Switch to Text, and look for actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the script as in path section complete path was not recorded by BlazeMeter plugin.

I just modified path accordingly and works.